# Visual Studio Code Error: 'Expected Comma json(514)"

Tags: html, mysql, json, pymysql

I used the python module `'PyMySQL'` to grab data from a MySQL database and convert it into a more accessible JSON format. Next to the name "Sentence" is a string of HTML code.

```
{
        "Time_Interval": "datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 14, 0, 0)", 
        "QueueID": 1018,
        "TemplateID": 18,
        "LineNum": 10, 
        "Sentence": "<FONT size="5"><B>\nHigh┬áWorkloads Hit┬áService Levels</FONT></B> \n<BR><FONT   size="4"><FONT style="text-transform: capitalize;">\ncalls and average handle time</FONT> Up So Average Service Level Down To 92.2%.</FONT>\n\n"
},
```

On the HTML string you'll see, at the beginning, it says `<FONT size="5">` and it's those quotations marks that seem to be tripping it up.

I think it wants me to put a semicolon there as it thinks it's meant to be the end of a line. In all honesty, I'm not too sure. This is my first time properly using JSON and SQL.
Does anyone know how to fix this so I can keep that all as one string?
You'll also see in the HTML code multiple `'┬á'` and `\n` bits. I know the second ones are python code to create a new line in a string, but I have no clue that the first ones are at all. Does anyone possibly know what those first ones are? And if it's possible to automatically remove the `\n` characters from the string? This is a SQL server for a project I've been assigned so I have no idea what those first characters are.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!
(First post on stack Overflow so sorry if it looks odd)

Comment: You have to escape the quotes in the string with a backslash: `\"` . You can also replace all double quotes with single quotes in the string, before you create the JSON-object. Whatever you like better. Should look like this in the end: `"Sentence": "<FONT size=\"5\"><B>\nHigh┬áWorkloads Hit┬áService Levels</FONT></B> \n<BR><FONT   size=\"4\"><FONT style=\"text-transform: capitalize;\">\ncalls and average handle time</FONT> Up So Average Service Level Down To 92.2%.</FONT>\n\n"` . The weird Symbols are most likely some special character, that can't be correctly translated to your charset.